# Matching colours with column values in gt

Tags: r, gt

I have a simple piece of code that tries to publish a table which colours columns according to the colour listed in the contents using the package gt.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("john", "paul", "ringo"),
                 fav_colour = c("red", "blue", "green"))

df %>% gt() %>% data_color(columns = fav_colour, colors = fav_colour)
```

However, as you can see the colours plotted do not match up correctly.

I appreciate that this is a known issue in gt, as described on [package github](https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/633) and that no fix has been implemented to the package yet.

I was wondering if either someone has discovered a workaround to this in gt or can recommend a different table publishing package that has equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ...

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df <- data.frame(name = c("john", "paul", "ringo"),
                 fav_colour = c("red", "blue", "green"))

df %>% 
  mutate(fav_colour = fct_inorder(fav_colour)) |> 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(columns = fav_colour, colors = as.character(fav_colour))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this - small error that reads: `Error in dplyr::group_vars(data) : 
  argument "data" is missing, with no default`
I can probably fix that but will have to come back to it shortly. 
Out of interest, what does the |> do?

Comment: `|>` is basically saying "then do this". It's the new native pipe in R that broadly does the same as the magrittr pipe `%>%`, i.e. passing forward the result of the previous line to the next. There are subtle differences but I have now switched to using the new native pipe.

Comment: Check if you have a recent R version. Or you can just use `%>%` instead of my `|>`

Comment: Fab! Works a treat :)